# CSS using border on one side, does not have same width near end?

Tags: html, css

Hi I am tring to implement something like below screenshot...

[image]

Here is what i am using

```
border-left: 5px solid #7AC0DA;
```

and it gives me this output

[image]

The border is not crisp enough, as you can see in this screenshot the border does not have same width near the ends. How do I correct this ?

Comment: The top and bottom having border width causes this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The border shows a bevel because the top and bottom have widths. You can do what you need using the pseudo-element `:before`

http://jsfiddle.net/sEWqW/3/

```
<label><input /></label>
```

CSS

```
label {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-left:0;
    padding:.1em .3em;
    position:relative;
}
label:before {
    display:block;
    content:".";
    color:transparent;
    font-size:0;
    border-left:5px solid #f24495;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    padding:1px 0;
    top:-1px;
    bottom:-1px;
}
label input{
    border:0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because the element has a border of `1px solid grey` already, and the blue has to expand.

Your best best would be to *not* use border styles on the `input`, but something like the following:

**HTML**

```
<label class="highlight clearfix">
  <span>Field name:</span>
  <input />
</label>
```

**CSS**

```
label span, label input { float: left }
label.highlight span { border-right: 5px solid blue }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that somewhere, there is a border-width for your border-top and bottom.
I see that you set a border only on left with border-left. Maybe you should try first to set border:0 and than in the same selector, use border-left.